# 95% Confidence interval interpretation

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, inference

If a best-fit value for the y-intercept is within the calculated 95% CI for the y-intercept, does that mean that it can be accepted as a true y-intercept?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be more specific about what you mean by the ''y-intercept''. Does this mean the intercept from the standard linear regression model:
$$ Y_i = \alpha + \beta'x_i + \epsilon_i \hspace{10pt} i= 1, \dots, n$$ 
Additionally, is the best fit value, as you describe it, the value of $\alpha$ which minimizes the residual sum of squares for your data?

Regardless, you may need to reconsider how you compute your confidence intervals if the best fit value is ever not contained in the interval. In general, one can write a confidence interval as $$
\text{point estimate} \pm (\text{critical value}) \times \text{standard error} , $$
so that the point estimate - or in your case, the ''best fit value'' - is always the center of the interval.

Finally, to answer your question, no. A confidence interval gives you a range of plausible values for your intercept. You should almost never make any statement that claims that you know the true value of an unknown parameter.

Comment: ah ,okay. I think that this question was more of a clarification on interpreting confidence intervals. Yes, the Y-intercept is from the standard regression model.

Comment: In the clarified scenario, the point estimate is always within the 95% CI. I assume user23658 wondered why there was any possibility for it to lie outside in your scenario. In general, all you know from a CI is that - assuming your model is correct - it will contain the true parameter value 95% of the time. It does not per-se say where in the CI the true parameter would be, if it is within the CI, nor does it tell you whether you are in one of the 5% of cases, where the CI does not contain the true value. Finally, looking at the CI provides no protection against a wrong model.